# Как вставить исходный код в листинг ассемблера на VS2017?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, ассемблер, visual-studio-2017

Есть транслятор VS2017, и есть программа на С++. Хочу получить ассемблерный листинг проекта. Листинг получается, но в нем нет строк исходного С++ кода. Перепробовал все ключи:

/FA

/FAc

/FAs

/FAcs

выводит только ассемблер, а строк исходного текста не выводит.

Что надо еще указать, чтобы транслятор включил в ассемблерный листинг строки исходного С++ кода в виде комментариев?

Comment: Опция `Assembly With Source Code (/FAs)` должна работать

Comment: Не работает. Ассемблерный код выводит, но в нем нет вставок исходного С++ кода.